# oneToMany JPA spring

Tags: single-page-application, one-to-many

I am trying to link two errors, but I am falling out

Here's a error:
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.proxy.ProxyBase.proxy_server in com.accounts.AllAccountsBase.proxies

First model

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "all_accounts")
public class AllAccountsBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "old_password")
    private String oldPassword;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "recovery_email")
    private String recoveryEmail;

    @Column(name = "recovery_pass")
    private String recoveryPass;

    @Column(name = "virt_machine")
    private String machineName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_data_id")
    private PersonalData personalData;

    @Column(name = "account_status")
    private Integer accountStatus;

    @Column(name = "time_update")
    private Timestamp timeUpdate;

    @Column(name = "server_group")
    private String serverGroup;

    @Column(name = "server", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String server;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "proxy",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Collection<ProxyBase> proxies = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

In the model, I added a relationship one to many, and vice versa in the other

Second model

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "proxy")
public class ProxyBase implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "server", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String server;

    @Column(name = "proxy_data")
    private String proxyData;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "all_accounts_server")
    private AllAccountsBase allAccountsBase;

}
```

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it differently:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "proxy")
public class ProxyBase implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "server", nullable = false)
    private String server;

    @Column(name = "proxy_data")
    private String proxyData;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "all_accounts")
public class AllAccountsBase implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "old_password")
    private String oldPassword;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "recovery_email")
    private String recoveryEmail;

    @Column(name = "recovery_pass")
    private String recoveryPass;

    @Column(name = "virt_machine")
    private String machineName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_data_id")
    private PersonalData personalData;

    @Column(name = "account_status")
    private Integer accountStatus;

    @Column(name = "time_update")
    private Timestamp timeUpdate;

    @Column(name = "server_group", nullable = false)
    private String serverGroup;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "proxy_key",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "server_group", referencedColumnName = "server_group"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proxy_server_group", referencedColumnName = "server"))
    private Collection<ProxyBase> proxies = new ArrayList<>();

}
```